Exe to apk .emulator as exe luncher automatically
I am developing app right now but it's only apk I want to make it public .
So Iam been thinking how to make pc version without re-coding in c++.
I found idea to add simple android emulator with apk and make a file called setup to install emulator and open apk app in it automatically, without feeling it's emulator, like it's app designed for pc .
Does any has idea or how to do it ?because I don't know .
Apk with android emulator merging to be exe format

Possible in general but I wouldn't recommend it. A typical emulator plus Android image has multiple GB and requires at least 2-4Gb RAM and without properly installed virtualization drivers sped will be very very slow even on a high-end PC. In conclusion you will waste a lot of effort into a system nobody wants to use.

exe and apk are two completely different things
